# Convert to date from unconventional format in R

Tags: r, date, format, as.date

I have dates formatted as character strings following the format of this example:

"Wednesday 18 May 2016"

Is there a way to convert it into date directly, maybe with as.Date(mystring,someformat) ?

Comment: `as.Date("Wednesday 18 May 2016", "%A %d %B %Y")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the `Wednesday` followed by space with `sub` and convert to 'Date'

```
as.Date(sub("^\\S+\\s+", "", str1), "%d %b %Y")
#[1] "2016-05-18"
```

If we are using `lubridate`, just use `dmy`

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(str1)
#[1] "2016-05-18 UTC"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Wednesday 18 May 2016"
```

Comment: Thanks, mtoto proposed a simpler answer in the comments, but i'm happy to learn about lubridate!